# Tensorflow: How the validation set improves the learning curve

Tags: validation, tensorflow, deep-learning

In the tutorial for [MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/tf/), it is shown that the dataset is split into three different sets: (1) *data_sets.train*, (2) *data_sets.validation* and (3) *data_sets.test*. However, in the training loop just the **data_sets.train** is used for training.

```
# Start the training loop.
for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):
  start_time = time.time()

  # Fill a feed dictionary with the actual set of images and labels
  # for this particular training step.
  feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(data_sets.train,
                             images_placeholder,
                             labels_placeholder)
```

And every `(step + 1) % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps` the model is evaluated so three different evaluations are gotten: (1) Training Data Eval, (2) Validation Data Eval and (3) Test Data Eval.

Usually, in Machine Learning, the validation set is used for fine-tuning the parameters of the model, and it improves the learning curve.

How does the validation set is employed in Tensorflow so that the learning curve improves?

Answer (score 2):

Because training in deep learning takes so long it takes way too long to use something like grid search or random search for hyperparameter optimization.

Validation set is mostly used to look out for overfitting on the train dataset during training. Then the model / hyperparameter are tweaked according to the validation set. This is done manually as far as I know.

The test set is something that has no influence in designing the algorithm to estimate the performance of the classifier on new unseen data.

Edit:

There are some techniques that use the validation set like EarlyStopping (https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) or reducing the learning rate when the validation error did not decreasing for x epochs (https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

I also noticed that in CAFFE something similar happens.
I just wasn't sure if there was a way to tweak the parameters according to the validation set. If it is manual, as you said, then it is necessary to use python so we can upgrade the hyperparameters while training.

Comment: Edit: expanded on adjusting the hyperparameters while training.